# Upload Scorm App to Azure

Tags: java, azure, github, web, scorm

I am attempting to migrate a Java based SCORM package that i'm using as a webapp to Azure. It is currently being hosted as a Github Page.

What is the easiest way to do this? I have attempted to create a webapp in the dashboard, and the app starts to load but it freezes.

Comment: Did you see any exceptions? You said your app starts, would you please post your log trace which you could find on KUDU?